# Create list of weeks, categories into month intervals

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a list of 53 weeks, categorized into months (these are retail months so they will make more sense to someone in retail).

I need the list to repeat up to 53 weeks, in intervals of 4-5-4.

See [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89c95/1) for example

I am wanting to write this in an SQL statement rather than having a table, and also not using a whole lot of unions. I'm sure there is a way using `rownum` and `connect-by` but I just can't think of the logic!

Comment: For those not in retail, what is a retail month?

Comment: @Lock do you need select statemetn?

Comment: @Verma- a retail month is just a different period- similar to a financial year. In retail, every week is given a number, so you can compare, for example, week 12 to week 12 last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following. Not ideal but it works:

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS WEEK_ID, 1 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+4 AS WEEK_ID, 2 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+9 AS WEEK_ID, 3 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+13 AS WEEK_ID, 4 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+17 AS WEEK_ID, 5 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+22 AS WEEK_ID, 6 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+26 AS WEEK_ID, 7 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+30 AS WEEK_ID, 8 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+35 AS WEEK_ID, 9 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+39 AS WEEK_ID, 10 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+43 AS WEEK_ID, 11 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT ROWNUM+48 AS WEEK_ID, 12 AS MONTH_ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT to_char(l_date,'WW') week_id ,
      to_char(l_date, 'mm') month_id
FROM
     (SELECT to_date('01/jan/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')+LEVEL-1 l_date
     FROM dual
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365
     ORDER BY 1
     )
ORDER BY WEEK_ID;
```

**EDITING** AS PER YOUR SQL FIDDLE table:

```
SELECT week_id,     MAX(month_id)
FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(l_date,'WW') week_id ,
          TO_CHAR(l_date, 'mm') month_id
     FROM
          (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'year')+LEVEL-1 l_date
          FROM dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365
          )
     )
GROUP BY week_id 
     ORDER BY WEEK_ID;
```

Comment: Not quite there. There is 63 rows returned.

Comment: could you point out some of the changes to be made for the result for above query

Comment: There should be 53 rows, not 63 rows. Week 05 appears twice. The first lot of months have 5 weeks, not 4..

Comment: @Lock, a week_id may have in two months , January 31st of 2013, and February 1st of 2013 is  in week_id 5. Please check again.

Comment: @Lock, I've updated my answer, Your sqlfiddle is not correctly inserted with the overlapping week_id with the month. check with your table data, and use min(month_id) or max(month_id) of your choice

Comment: Sorry about the fiddle. It's still not correct- the first 12 rows are all blocks of 4, not 4-5-4